# Different results of the integrate $\int \frac{\sin (\pi s)}{(s-0.5)^2+90} \,ds$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Following results are given of big different values. I think `NIntegrate`'s one is right but others are not explained.

```
Plot[Integrate[Sin[π s]/((s - 0.5)^2 + 90), {s, 0, x}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Integrate[Sin[π s]/((s - 1/2)^2 + 90), {s, 0, x}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[NIntegrate[Sin[π s]/((s - 0.5)^2 + 90), {s, 0, x}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integrate` seems to choke on your integrand, at least on my machine. However, I was able to use **Rubi** (the [RUle Based Integrator](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/)) to quickly obtain an analytical form of your integral (note that I swapped 1/2 for the 0.5 value you had in your original expression):

```
analytical[s_] = Int[Sin[Pi s]/((s - 1/2)^2 + 90), s]
```

> -((I Cosh[3 Sqrt[10] Pi] CosIntegral[1/2 (1 + 6 I Sqrt[10]) Pi - Pi s]) / (6 Sqrt[10])) + (I Cosh[3 Sqrt[10] Pi] CosIntegral[-(1/2) (1 - 6 I Sqrt[10]) Pi + Pi s]) / (6 Sqrt[10]) + (Sinh[3 Sqrt[10] Pi] SinIntegral[1/2 (1 - 6 I Sqrt[10]) Pi - Pi s]) / (6 Sqrt[10]) + (Sinh[3 Sqrt[10] Pi] SinIntegral[1/2 (1 + 6 I Sqrt[10]) Pi - Pi s]) / (6 Sqrt[10])

Let us then calculate the value of the definite integral analytically:

```
plotargument[x_] = analytical[x] - analytical[0];
```

We can now plot this value using appropriately **high working precision**:

```
Plot[plotargument[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is the **same result you obtained with** `NIntegrate`. I think the other results may have been affected by a lack of precision.

NB: notice that, at regular MachinePrecision, the plot above does not look good at all. It is actually quite surprising, at least to me, how sensitive the plot is to the `WorkingPrecision`:

```
Plot[plotargument[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> #,
    ImagePadding -> {{45, All}, {All, All}}, ImageSize -> Medium,
    Epilog -> Inset[
      Style[Text["prec = " <> ToString[#]], Large, Red],
      Scaled[{0.85, 0.2}]
      ]
    ] & /@ {25, 26, 27, 28};
Column@%
```

[image: dependence on WorkingPrecision]

Comment: In 10.1 on Linux, the `Integrate` call runs just fine and gives the same result that you obtained.

Comment: @halirutan That's surprising! I tried again just now, and I couldn't get any result in under three minutes. Encourage by your remark, I added the assumption that $x$ and $s$ are real numbers, and then I did get the same result, but it still took roughly two minutes! I'm on MMA 10.1 on Win7-64 bit

Comment: The terms of the result of the integral are rather large, over 10^20 for most of the domain and up to over 10^22.  At machine precision, one would expect round-off errors around 10^7 or more.  To get accurate answers around 10^-3, you'd need well over 10 more digits of precision than machine precision, so 28 seems about right.  Seems like a really bad antiderivative for numerical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Although `MaxRecursion` is not an option for `Integrate`,  if I use `MaxRecursion->10` I got the plot fast.

```
Timing[Plot[
   Integrate[Sin[\[Pi] s]/((s - 0.5)^2 + 90), {s, 0, x}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 10], {x, 0, 1}] // Quiet]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I want to know why I should do like your try or what processes.

Comment: @JunhoLee I am not sure I understand you correctly. If want to know how did I get this solution it is trial and error. If you meant the solution should not used that is fine I just have this idea and I thought to share it.